# Red or Rebol 3: choice is hard

Tags: rebol, rebol3, red

I have tested Red, as for the language It's easy enough as it doesn't differ much from Rebol. But I really miss some console features, the most annoying for me is

red --do 
and 
autoloading script

which are missing. Are they planned ?

Comment: Seriously, please consider taking these kinds of discussion oriented questions [to Red's chat](https://gitter.im/red/home) or [here on the Rebol chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol).  StackOverflow is not the appropriate venue, and your reputation is high enough I would think you must have a sense of this by now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `--do` command-line feature is planned for 0.6.4. Autoloading script is not planned for now, as it represents a potentially big security hole. Moreover, in Red, you can easily compile your own Red console for running your scripts, and include there whatever Red code you want integrated. You would need to download Red [sources](https://github.com/red/red) for that, then from the repo's root folder:

```
red -r %environment/console/console.red
```

You can edit the `%console.red` script to include whatever you want.